# database design for a payment system

Tags: logging, database-design, payment

I have four table as below:

**FEES**

```
fees_id, interest, amount, total_amount, status_id, is_recurring  recurring_status  from_date   to_date      payment_id
    F001     1.50  1000    1015          1          N             NULL              2018-11-01  2018-11-01   1
    F002     2.00  2000    1020          1          Y             COMPLETE          2018-11-01  2018-11-20   2
```

**PAYMENT**

```
id, amount,  payment_date, txn_id, bnk_name, txn_status, pay_mode, dd_no, dd_date,   chk_no, chk_date
1   1015     2018-11-11    TXN0001 SBI       1           1         NULL   NULL       NULL    NULL
2   1020     2018-11-20    NULL    NULL      NULL        3         DNO001 2018-11-19 NULL    NULL
```

**PAY_MODES**

```
id  name   display
------------------
1   ONLINE Y
2   CASH   Y
3   DRAFT  Y
4   CHECK  Y
```

**PAYMENT_STATUS**

```
id  status  display
-------------------
1   PAID    Y
2   UNPAID  Y
```

A fee can be paid by any of the four pay modes.

I have few questions:

- Is it ok (in this scenario) to have one payment table for all pay modes OR is there any better option?
- A fee can be recurring (paid every month until its recurring status is completed). How can I handle these payments?
- Do I need to store each payment response (in case of online payment) whether success, fail or whatever. If yes, should I use a separate table or store in a file?

Answer (score 5):

Que: Is it ok (in this scenario) to have one payment table for all pay modes OR is there any better option?

> Yes, all the payment should be in one Payment Table. This helps to
>   maintain the transactional integrity constraint. Also, it will helpful
>   for you in future while generating various reports

Que: A fee can be recurring (paid every month until its recurring status is completed). How can I handle these payments?

> You should have another table for maintaining the recurring payments
>   record as Subscription table and at every recurring payment event of a
>   record insert new entry into payment table. So, One subscription
>   record will be related to multiple payment entries.

Que: Do I need to store each payment response (in case of online payment) whether success, fail or whatever. If yes, should I use a separate table or store in a file?

> Yes, you should store the payment response in the same payment table
>   record. This will help you out in the failover detection as well as
>   major help in Audit Log.