# Database design for recurring fine payment

Tags: database, payment, recurring-billing

I have a table Fine

```
fine_id  amount  date           fine_type  is_rec  rec_status 
F001     100     2018-12-01     1          TRUE    INCOMPLETE
F002     10000   2018-12-02     4          FALSE   NULL
```

and a Payments table

```
id   fine_id    amount   paymode   txn_id   txn_status
1    F002       10000    ONLINE    TXN001   1
```

A fine can be recurring, i.e. user has to pay fine amount every month until its rec_status is updated as "completed" by the admin.

1. Payment table stores only successful payments, for failed payments i have made a separate table (Is it Ok) ?
2. How can i handle recurring fines in this scenario ?
3. To check whether a fine has been paid i am checking payments table whether an entry exists there or not. Is it ok ?

**EDIT-1**

Fine Master

```
fine_id  amount  entry_date     fine_type  is_rec  rec_status    rec_type
F001     100     2018-12-01     1          TRUE    INCOMPLETE    Monthly
F002     10000   2018-12-02     4          FALSE   NULL
F003     10000   2018-12-02     4          TRUE    INCOMPLETE    Yearly
```

Fine

```
rec_fine_id    fine_id  amount  for_month  for_year  is_paid
RF001          F001     100     022018     NULL      TRUE
RF002          F003     10000   NULL       2018      TRUE
RF003          F002     10000   NULL       NULL      TRUE
RF004          F001     100     032018     NULL      FALSE
```

Payments

```
id   rec_fine_id  amount paymode  txn_id   txn_status  is_successful pay_date
 1   RF001        100    ONLINE   TXN001   1           true         2018-02-10
 2   RF003        10000  ONLINE   TXN010   1           true         2018-10-10
 3   RF002        10000  ONLINE   TXN011   1           true         2018-07-11
```

Comment: At the very least you need a way of storing which month a given payment is for, in the ``payments`` table.

Comment: You have not provided enough information. For example, are you trying to track which months in which to expect a payment? Are you tracking which months were paid or not paid? You current design tracks just the payments without regard for months. You are not even storing the date of the payment. Tip: If you do want to track months in their entirety, I suggest using text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates) format: YYYY-MM such as `2018-02` for February 2018.

Comment: Similar, possible duplicate: [*database design for a payment system*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53293775/642706)

Comment: i am storing payment date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [database design for a payment system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293775/database-design-for-a-payment-system)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have three tables: `FineMaster` (holding master information about fine, whether rec_status is completed or not. There will be only one entry for a fine), `Fine` (holding recurring fine details and have parent reference to FineMaster), `Payment` (holding payment information for every fine recurrence).

1. No need for separate tables. Just have one table for payment. Have a flag,  `IssuccessfulPayment`. This flag will tell whether payment was successful or not.
2. Recurring fines can be handled using `FineMaster`. Refer to the first paragraph in the answer.
3. I would suggest you to maintain recurring fine payment information in the Fine table. Have a flag, `IsPaymentCompleted` in the Fine table. If the payment is successful for a recurring fine, update the Fine table that payment is successful. For a single fine, there could be multiple payments as well. I would suggest you to maintain the recurring fine payment information in the Fine table.

Comment: I have edited my question, please check other questions also

Comment: @KuldeepThakur, updated my answer based on the edited question

Comment: Because once the fine is entered by the admin and he selects it as recurring and recurrring period (monthly, yearly) after that how to generate new entry for recurring fine automatically (monthly or yearly).

Comment: @KuldeepThakur, which database it is ? You can have a date table and use CROSS APPLY and insert multiple rows in the fine table using recurrence

Comment: i am using postgres

Comment: @KuldeepThakur, Ok. Based on the recurrence, have a stored procedure which inserts recurrence data into fine table. Have a date table containing calendar dates. [Datedimension table](https://medium.com/@duffn/creating-a-date-dimension-table-in-postgresql-af3f8e2941ac) & use CROSS Apply to insert values into Fine table

Comment: can you please give me an example

Comment: @KuldeepThakur, Once you create date dimension, you can get the list of dates, based on the recurrence pattern. Say, if it is every week Monday, group by the week number, day 1 and select date and insert into Fine table. [Create Date Dimension and using it](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). This is SQL Server. but, you can get idea on how to implement the same for PostGres.

Comment: should every finemaster entry be in fine table whether is recurring or not. I have edited my question for demonstration.

Comment: @KuldeepThakur, Yes. FineMaster is master table for every fine. Fine table is transactional table for fines corresponding to FineMaster. If there is not recurrence, then there will be only one entry in both FineMaster and Fine table. Every table has a purpose.

Comment: should i also stroe fine-master id in payments table

Comment: @KuldeepThakur, If payments are related to fine recurrence, then you have grand parent (fine master) -> parent (fine) -> child (payment) relationship and you dont need finemasterid in payment. If payments are related to fine master then you need to store it.